# How to match the response value to dropdown

Tags: angularjs

When user select the country then I will store that country value in backend database by forming request.

In json response I am getting the selected country as "country" but I am not able to compare that response country value "country" with dropdown (which contains country

HTML:

```
<select name="country" class="drop3 countries" required  ng-model="model.country" placeholder="select" id="countryId sel1" ng-options="country for model.country in countries track by countryId">
```

I am using an external js which will popup all the country and state based on selected country and city based on selected state.

External js link : `<script src="http://iamrohit.in/lab/js/location.js"></script>`

Comment: how do you set the country? create a fiddle or plunker link

Comment: If I select the country from dropdown, the selected country will be assigned to "$scope.model.country". I am not able to match response country value with dropdown because, country value in response is string and  i need to compare the string with dropdown value which contains id as well

Comment: Does that mean you need country value of the selected item in dropdown? If I read your question correct, then, try (assuming countryName is the property you need) - `ng-options="country.countryName as country.countryName for country in countries track by countryId"` -  now, your `model.country` will have the selected "Name" of the country

Comment: It is not getting assigned.